# How can userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) cause a crash even with nothing in the body of the function?

Tags: ios, unusernotificationcenter

I have an app with notifications that have notification actions. Everything has worked well for years using a class that conforms to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and handling the actions in its `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler)` method.

Recently, I refactored a lot of my app’s code to use async/await. As a result, I switched to the async version of the delegate method, `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) async`, which no longer uses the completion handler.

After releasing an update that used the async version of the method, I started seeing a ton of crashes on my device and out in the wild. Here’s an example, with the app name removed:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  16

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x197ba2248 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x190f63a68 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   Foundation                             0x19252281c _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
3   UIKitCore                              0x19aa4fe94 -[UIApplication _performBlockAfterCATransactionCommitSynchronizes:] + 404
4   UIKitCore                              0x19aa5c20c -[UIApplication _updateStateRestorationArchiveForBackgroundEvent:saveState:exitIfCouldNotRestoreState:updateSnapshot:windowScene:] + 528
5   UIKitCore                              0x19aa5c4d0 -[UIApplication _updateSnapshotAndStateRestorationWithAction:windowScene:] + 144
6                                          0x1006c36a8 @objc closure #1 in NotificationDelegate.userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) + 132
7                                          0x1006c37d1 partial apply for @objc closure #1 in NotificationDelegate.userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) + 1
8                                          0x10049d845 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable @async () -> () + 1
9                                          0x1005ceb3d thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable @async () -> ()partial apply + 1
10                                         0x1005cea01 specialized thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable @async () -> (@out A) + 1
11                                         0x1005cec75 partial apply for specialized thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable @async () -> (@out A) + 1
12  libswift_Concurrency.dylib             0x1a1dce2d1 completeTaskWithClosure(swift::AsyncContext*, swift::SwiftError*) + 1
```

Based on testing, the crash happens when taking action on a notification, like tapping the notification to open the app, for example (responding to `UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier`).

From the delegate method, I pass the center and response to a method that handles the processing asynchronously. In an attempt to narrow down the issue, I eliminated one piece at a time out of my `processResponse(_:didReceive:) async` method, until I was left with nothing but a print statement:

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse)
async
{
    await processResponse(center,
                          response: response)
}

private func processResponse(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                             response: UNNotificationResponse)
async
{
    print("Do almost nothing...")
}
```

Even this minimal example results crashes. How can I troubleshoot this further to get the `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) async` method working without these crashes?

The way I set up my notifications is pretty straightforward. In my AppDelegate, before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I set up the NotificationController (responsible for setting up and scheduling notifications), and then the NotificationDelegate (responsible for handling actions) as lazy vars so I can pass the NotificationController into the NotificationDelegate:

```
private lazy var notificationController =
    NotificationController(statsProvider: statsProvider)

private lazy var notificationDelegate: NotificationDelegate =
    NotificationDelegate(
        notificationController: notificationController
    )
```

Then, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I set the delegate on `UNUserNotificationCenter.current()`:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = notificationDelegate
```

I don’t think any of the setup is abnormal, unless I’m missing something, so I can’t see how the nearly empty delegate method could still be crashing.

---

To illustrate the issue in isolation, I created a demo app to replicate the crash I'm seeing. I would like to know the proper way to use the `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) async` delegate method without crashing.

This simple app sends a notification 5 seconds after it is launched. Tapping the notification to open the app is supposed to schedule another notification 5 seconds later, but the app crashes.

To replicate this, create a new iOS app project with UIKit and give it Push Notifications capability. Here is the AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    private lazy var notificationController = NotificationController()

    private lazy var notificationDelegate = NotificationDelegate(
        notificationController: notificationController
    )

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
        -> Bool
    {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = notificationDelegate

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession,
                     options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)
    -> UISceneConfiguration
    {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
}
```

NotificationController:

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationController {

    init()
    {
        Task {
            await setUpPermissions()
        }
    }

    func scheduleNotification()
    async
    {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = "Test notification"
        content.sound = .default

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(
            timeInterval: 5,
            repeats: false
        )

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(
            identifier: "Test",
            content: content,
            trigger: trigger
        )

        do {
            try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                .add(request)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    private func setUpPermissions()
    async
    {
        let authorizationStatus = await UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            .notificationSettings()
            .authorizationStatus
        
        switch authorizationStatus {

        case .notDetermined:

            do {
                let granted = try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                    .requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert])
                
                if granted
                {
                    await scheduleNotification()
                }
            }
            catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
            
        case .authorized:

            await scheduleNotification()

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

NotificationDelegate:

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationDelegate: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    private let notificationController: NotificationController
    
    init(notificationController: NotificationController)
    {
        self.notificationController = notificationController
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification)
    async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions
    {
        return [.banner, .sound]
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse)
    async
    {
        print("didReceive response")
        
        if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier
        {
            await notificationController.scheduleNotification()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this even crashes without the attempt to schedule another notification:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse)
async
{
    print("didReceive response")
}
```

How can this `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) async` be used properly to avoid the crash?

Comment: Are you crashing at launch?

Comment: Sorry one more question. If you simply delete your `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async` and replace it with `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`, does the crash go away?

Comment: Your code looks wired. UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate type is expected when setting a delegate but why do you get a `NotificationDelegate ` type?

Comment: @matt I don’t ever see or experience and symptoms of the crash, I just see it in the crash logs on my device. So I don’t think it’s happening at launch. When I replace with the completionHandler version containing only the print statement in the body, like I do in this example, I do not get the crash.

Comment: @kakaiikaka The `NotificationDelegate` object is one that I created that conforms to `UNUserNofiticationCenterDelegate`

Comment: "I don’t ever see or experience and symptoms of the crash, I just see it in the crash logs on my device" I don't get that. If you don't experience any crash then you are not crashing and there's no visible issue.

Comment: @matt I meant there is never a case where I am using the app and it disappears from the screen, or try to open from a notification or do a notification action and it closes. But it shows up in the crash logs on my device and in Xcode for users of the app, and some have reported inconsistencies when using notification actions, so I’m trying to fix it so these crashes stop showing up.

Comment: So switch back to the completion handler version and file a bug with Apple.

Comment: @matt The code I need to run in the method in my app is async, which is why I was using the async version of the delegate method. I tried putting an async method inside a Task and calling the completion handler inside that, but that was also giving me the same issue.

Comment: You say "the code I need to run ... is async", but then how were you calling it before? I just don't believe you need to do it that way. But I can't see your code. Indeed, you didn't really show _any_ code of any significance. So maybe this is an interesting question but I have no idea, because you have given no information. If you actually want help, try being a bit more generous with your details.

Comment: @matt I was using the completionHandler version before a major re-write of a lot of my app's code to use async/await, but my app's code was a mess before the re-write so I don't want to go back to that. I didn't include more code because I am trying to isolate the issue I'm seeing here with a crash even when there is only a print statement in the delegate method. I'll continue to investigate and test.

Comment: If you are not willing to dive far enough into your code in this question to make this a viable Stack Overflow question, I suggest deleting the question. Maybe come back when you know more or are more willing to cooperate with those who wish to assist you.

Comment: @matt Thanks I'll come back and update it more when I figure out more about what's going on here or if it's a bug is iOS, since it is reproducible based on what I have here so far.

Comment: That's not true. First, I assume that one would need to receive an actual notification action from the user in order to get the crash; you aren't going to get any crash merely because there's a function sitting there that is never called. Second, there are unknowns in your question (you have not even shown what a NotificationController or NotificationDelegate is). Please review the notion of a [mcve]. When you have supplied enough code to allow me to reproduce the problem, we will have something to talk about. Until then, I have voted to close on the ground of insufficiency.

Comment: @matt I found a workaround and posted that as an answer, but will also be creating as separate project to reproduce the issue so I can file a bug with Apple and I will update the question with more code from that example.

Comment: Cool, but I notice that in order to answer the question you had to change the information in the question rather considerably, supporting my contention that you were not giving sufficient information.

Comment: @matt Yes, I adjusted it so that my answer would make more sense once I found the solution. The behavior was still the same with crashes. I will add to the question once I create a standalone app to isolate the problem.

Comment: For me it looks like a bug in iOS. @gohnjanotis please report it to the Apple. That problem still occurs in iOS 17. Completion handle have somewhere `fatalError(Thread.isMainThread, "Call mast be made on main thread")`, but Apple's documentation doesn't mentioning that. And it's firing only sometimes with unknown reasons. I think it's Apple's responsibility to dispatch in desired queues what they want to perform. Also it's cruel to demand from @gohnjanotis reproduction steps for black box.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same exact issue.

It looks like the assertion failure is caused by the method being called on a background thread.

If you annotate the delegate method with `@MainActor` it fixes the issue:

```
@MainActor
public func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse
) async {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: This is the way, using async version and marked as MainActor

Comment: This approach fixes crash but there are two compiler warnings: `Non-sendable type 'UNNotificationResponse' in parameter of the protocol requirement satisfied by main actor-isolated instance method 'userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:)' cannot cross actor boundary` and `Non-sendable type 'UNUserNotificationCenter' in parameter of the protocol requirement satisfied by main actor-isolated instance method 'userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:)' cannot cross actor boundary `

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution to get around the crash.

During testing, one of the crashes gave me the error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Call must be made on main thread'`

That seemed odd since I was just doing a print statement, but through experimenting I was able to find a workaround so I can still use asynchronous code without a crash even when using the `withCompletionHandler` version of the delegate method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    Task {
        await processResponse(center,
                              response: response)
        Task { @MainActor in
            completionHandler()
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving me a compiler warning `Capture of 'completionHandler' with non-sendable type '() -> Void' in a '@Sendable' closure`, but at least it works without the crash.

Note that if I do not call the completionHandler on the MainActor the crash still happens.

Also, I am still confused about why the async delegate method crashes when taking action on a notification, even when it only does this one print statement, without starting any other tasks or switching to any other actors:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse)
async
{
    print("Do almost nothing...")
}
```

Comment: Never use DispatchQueue inside a Task. That's unsupported and you're mixing apples and oranges; DispatchQueue and async/await are incompatible (in effect, they are opposites).

Comment: @matt Thanks, I've updated it to use the Task way to call on the main thread

Comment: Good but then I don't see why your whole task is not marked mainactor. If you've written your async code correctly, `processResponse` should be in an actor if you want it to run on a background thread.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I am still learning async/await and actors, so I will look into trying to improve my async code that way even when using the completionHandler version of the delegate method. In this case I was still seeing the crash when using the async version of the delegate method with just the print statement, without starting any other tasks or async functions, so I was trying to understand that why that was crashing for being off the main thread and how to avoid that crash. I'll still plan to update the question with a full example that uses a sample app to illustrate that isolated issue.

Comment: The point is that if you would actually show what you are doing, people can help you. You refuse so you don't get any help. It's pretty simple.

Comment: @matt Didn't refuse, just didn't want to include unnecessary code outside the scope of the question. Added a fully reproducible example app to the question to illustrate the issue further.